# tail recursive directory traversal in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust, tail-recursion

Please evaluate and help me understand if my attempted implementation of a tail recursive directory traversal function is actually tail recursive or not. I wrote this from my understanding that a tail recursion happens if the recursive call is the last thing done by a function. The output of traversal matches the nested directory structure I had while testing, but I am not sure if this really qualifies as a tail recursive function because the one example which I could find in google (factorial), it uses an accumulator while I do not use it because I cannot figure out where to use it either if needed one.

```
use std::fs;

fn traverse_directory(directory: &str, filenames: &mut Vec<String>) {
    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(directory) {
        entries.for_each(|entry| {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                let path = entry.path();
                if path.is_file() {
                    filenames.push(path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy().into_owned());
                } else if path.is_dir() {
                    return traverse_directory(&path.to_string_lossy(), filenames)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = Vec::new();
    traverse_directory("/tmp", &mut list);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

If this is not tail recursive, can someone kindly explain why it is not, and how this could be made one?

I wrote this in Rust because I was following an algorithm tutorial made for Rust programming language, but my question is language agnostic.

Thank you.

Comment: My personal assumption is that you should know if that's a tail recursive or not.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj What do you mean by that? If you're just telling the asker that they should already know the answer to their question, that's not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is Not Tail-Recursive, Because You Recurse from a Closure

The `return traverse_directory(`...`)` statement would be tail-recursive from `traverse_directory`, but it is being called from a closure.  That’s equivalent to calling from a named helper function.  The function and the anonymous closure within it could still be mutually-recursive if the closure were tail-called, and get most of the same optimizations, but that is not the case.  It is called from a `for_each`, and must create a new stack frame each time so that the loop can resume.

(I deleted my original first paragraph, because your use of `return` from a closure is correct, just not tail-recursion.)

### Rust Does Not Guarantee Tail-Call Optimization Anyway

Tail-recursive algorithms in Rust might compile to unoptimized calls that eat up the stack, and you will not be warned when this happens.  I’ve generally had good results with functions that have moved or dropped all their local values that aren’t references when they tail-recurse, and therefore have no need to keep anything alive during the tail-call and drop it after, but this will not be reliable in Rust, unless the language changes.

Indeed, [testing with Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bfdc63oad) shows that this call is *not* optimized as a tail-call.

Graydon Hoare has called [his announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605150233/https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-April/003557.html) “one of the saddest posts ever written on the subject,” and later said that this was one of the times he was outvoted on the design.

### The List Should be the Return Value

It does not make much sense to require the caller to pass in `&mut Vec::new()` so the function can fill it.  Just create the `Vec` yourself and pass it back.  This allows callers to chain and compose this function, and is one less thing that can go wrong with the public API.

If I were writing a tail-recursive function with an accumulator in a functional language, I would probably write the version with the accumulator as a private helper, have the public function call it with the accumulator set to 0/an empty list/whatever, and return the folded value.  This keeps the benefits of immutable data, but in a language like Haskell, it’s also the only real option.

In Rust, it can sometimes be an optimization to pass around references instead of moving parameters, but that is not as true for an efficiently-moveable type like `Vec`.  If the compiler is able to optimize out tail-recursion, it is also able to optimize out a move from a parameter to itself.

### Refactor with Either a `for` Loop or an Iterator

#### If You Use a `for` Loop

This is the simplest solution.  Create a new `mut Vec<String>`.  For each element in the list, either `push` the name of the regular file to the result `Vec`, or `append` the list returned by a recursive call to the function.

#### If You Use Iterators

As an alternative to `for_each`, you could write a quasi-functional solution here.  Write a helper function that turns a `DirEntry` into either a sequence of all files within a recursive descent of the directory, or a singleton of its filename.  Then, do a `flat_map` over all sequences generated by the directory entries.

Iterators often lead to elegant, fluent code, but here you have to pick your poison.  Each directory item adds either no names (if invalid), one name (if it is a regular file or symlink) or at least one but possibly more (if it is a directory).  That means you will have to convert the result of all three cases into some common type.  One of them, a recursive call, will return a `Vec<String>`.

You can therefore:

- Represent all three cases as a `Vec<String>`, whose length might be 0 or 1, and do a lot of tiny heap allocations for all the singletons.
- Convert all three cases into a `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>` and use runtime polymorphism, creating many tiny objects on the heap.
- Convert all three cases into a `&[String]` without using the heap, but now be forced to `clone` each borrowed `&String`.

An implementation that does the first of these (which should be simpler and have less overhead than the other two):

```rs
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};

pub fn traverse_directory(directory: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    fn dirent_helper(entry: DirEntry) -> Vec<String> {
        let filetype = entry.file_type().expect("Invalid file type");

        if filetype.is_file() || filetype.is_symlink() {
            vec!{entry.path().to_str().expect("Invalid filename").to_string()}
        } else if filetype.is_dir() {
            traverse_directory(entry.path().to_str().expect("Invalid directory"))
        } else {
            Vec::new()
        }
    }

    fs::read_dir(directory)
        .expect("Error reading directory")
        .flat_map(|entry| dirent_helper(entry.expect("Invalid directory entry")))
        .collect()
}


pub fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", traverse_directory("."));
}
```

For simplicity, this panics on any error (including not having read permission on any directory), but you can change that behavior to return a `std::io::Result` (perhaps with the `?` operator) or silently ignore them and return an empty list.  It also does not return the names of empty directories, which you might want it to.

#### You Could Also `fold`

Since you have a sequence of `DirEntry` objects and want to accumulate a list of pathnames, a better way to do that might be as a `fold` that appends to the accumulator.  This mixes in some non-functional operations in Rust (since `Vec::append` and `Vec::push` are implemented as side-effect functions on `mut` data).

```rs
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};

pub fn traverse_directory(directory: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    fn dirent_helper(mut list: Vec<String>, entry: DirEntry) -> Vec<String> {
        let filetype = entry.file_type().expect("Invalid file type");

        if filetype.is_file() || filetype.is_symlink() {
            list.push(entry.path().to_str().expect("Invalid filename").to_string())
        } else if filetype.is_dir() {
            list.append(&mut traverse_directory(
                entry.path().to_str().expect("Invalid directory")))
        }

        list
    }

    fs::read_dir(directory)
        .expect("Error reading directory")
        .map(|entry| entry.expect("Invalid directory entry"))
        .fold(Vec::new(), dirent_helper)
}


pub fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", traverse_directory("."));
}
```

This is a nearly-zero-cost abstraction for what you were doing.  ([See for yourself on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/5cvqWccfn))  The path that does not recursively descend compiles to a loop with no temporary objects created on the heap.  All the gory details stay inside the function, hidden from the caller.  However, there is one unnecessary move of `list` per iteration, costing four instructions on X86-64.  (This is a missed optimization: since `dirent_helper` is a local function that cannot be called from anywhere else, the compiler could have passed `list` in the same registers it used for the return value, and could then have modified it in-place.)

### Don’t Shadow so Many Names

You re-use `entry` something like three times in a row.  This is confusing to a maintainer, and also runs the risk of a typo making the compiler think it should use an earlier version.

Comment: FYI: https://mail.mozilla.org is not reachable for me (Germany).

Comment: @RichardNeumann I’ve replaced it with a link to archive.org for now.

Comment: Thank you for the godbolt link. Appreciate it to introduce such a wonderful tool. May I ask which part of the asm tells that it's not tail-call optimised?

Comment: @nohup You’re welcome. You can right-click on the `return` statement that you hope might be optimized, and `Reveal linked code`. (Note that, if a line of code is optimized out, it might not be highlighted at all.) It will show you that one of the instructions this compiles to is `call qword ptr [rip + example::traverse_directory@GOTPCREL]`. If this had been an eliminated tail-call, this would have been a `jmp` to a label.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you very much for your kind explanation. I compared the asm generated by both the implementations and it makes much more sense now.